# What does the -Pcommon command do in maven command prompt

Tags: maven

I see that none of the tasks in pom.xml are getting executed when -Pcommon command is used during Maven installation. What exactly does the -Pcommon command do and how can this issue be resolved?

Comment: This is really too broad. Look up the documentation on profiles.

Answer (score 0):

The flag `-Pname` activates the profile with name `name`

What it is done after that ? It depends on your pom.xml. All plugins defined into the profile `name` will be executed.

[See the documentation here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Comment: Oh got it thanks. But it looks like the no tasks is running in the profile that is being used with -P

Answer (score 0):

The `-P` option on the command line specifies a profile to enable during the build. in the example you give, it is activating the *common* profile. The effects of that profile depend on what has been configured within the POM.

Comment: Profiles could be defined in settings.xml or parent poms.  run mvn help:effective-pom to see the final pom pom with everything included

Comment: Oh got it thanks. But it looks like the no tasks is running in the profile that is being used with -P